# Right appraoch to use to Create csv out of php array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

When i var_dump the contents of my array, i get the following results. I would like to be able to put the following contents into a csv file. For simplicity reasons, i have not displayed all the values of the array

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => NEWS 1
        [1] => 00
        [2] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => NEWS 1
        [1] => 01
        [2] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => NEWS 1
        [1] => 02
        [2] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => NEWS 1
        [1] => 03
        [2] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => NEWS 1
        [1] => 04
        [2] => 0
    )
)
```

I would like to be able to insert the contents of that array into a csv file. My final csv file should like this

```
NEWS 1,0,0,0,0,0
```

I have tried several methods without sucess. So useless to post my code here. I would like to start from scratch. If some one can advise me on the right apparoach to use or propose me some code, it will be very great

Comment: What several method did you tried?

Comment: Give the function for that a shot: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php Just loop through the array and execute that for each entry... there's even an example on the manual page.

Comment: the example in that link will return 3 lines in the csv file. My problem is i would like to have only one line in the csv file as i explained in the post

Answer (score 1):

I can give you this code I wrote long time ago.. it creates a csv line from an array... maybe it can inspire you. It is in a class called CSVWriter.

```
private static function writeFile($handle, $data, $pos) {
    if(count($data) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $element = $pos === 0 || $pos === count($data) - 1 ? $data[$pos] : ';'.$data[$pos];
        $fwrite = fwrite($handle, $element);

        if($fwrite === false || ($pos + 1 === count($data))) {
            return $fwrite;
        } else {
            CSVWriter::writeFile($handle, $data, ++$pos);
        }
    }
}
```